# laravelでボタン押下後に画面遷移できない

Tags: php, laravel

laravelでボタン押下後に画面遷移できない。

設置したボタンを押下すると、指定のページに遷移するようにしたいがうまくいかない。エラーは表示されず、同じhomeにとどまるのみ。

web.php のルーティング設定がうまくいっていない？

**実行環境:**
laravel 6
php 7.4

---

**web.php**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/home', function() { return view('home');});
//追加
        Route::get('/edit', 'Auth\AuthController@edit');
```

**Authcontroller**

```php
public function edit()
    {
        $hello = 'Guten Morgen';
        return view('auth.edit', compact('hello'));
    }
```

**views/auth/edit**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HelloHello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ $hello }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**views/partials/header**

```
<li><a href="{{url('/edit')}}">テスト</a></li>
```

Comment: ブラウザのアドレスバーに直接URLを入力して遷移してみるとどうなりますか？

Comment: keitaro_so
ありがとうございます。
強制的にhomeに戻るので、どうやらリダイレクトされているようです。
ログイン処理が詰まったcontrollerでもあったので、同じコントローラーにするとリダイレクトかかるようになっているんでしょうか。もう少し調べてみます。